# Using JavaScript localStorage for input form data

Tags: javascript, html

I have two HTML pages with simple forms. I want to save text input from index.html using localStorage when a user clicks "Submit" and make this value appear in a text field of html1.html. I think there might be a problem with my implementation of *retrieveName()* function. What may be improved to make it work correctly?

**index.html**

```html
<form name="form1" method="post" action="html1.html">
  <label>Name:
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="lastName" />
  </label>
  <input type="submit" name="submitName" value="Submit" onclick = "submitName()">

  <script>
    function submitName() {
      var userName = document.getElementById("fname");
      localStorage.setItem("lastName", userName.value);
    }
  </script>
</form>
```

**html1.html**

```html
<body onload="retrieveName()">
  <form name="form2">
    <br>

    <label>Last Name:
      <input type="text" id="lName" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" name="submitLastName" value="Save" />

    <script>
      var x = document.getElementById("lName");

      function retrieveName() {
        var text = localStorage.getItem("textValue");
        x.value = text;
      }
    </script>
  </form>

</body>
```

Comment: Nothing calls the `submitName()` function (in the code shown, anyway).

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks, I've missed it. Just edited the code and added submitName() method. But it still doesn't work..

Comment: You cannot use `submitName()` as a function name. I have tried this over and over it will not work unless I set the function name to something else. Simply change the name of your function and this should work just fine. Example: `SaveName()`

Comment: @NewToJS Wow!!! Thanks!! For some reason it works after I've changed the name of submitName() function to mySubmit(). Without using event.preventdefault(). What could be the reason for such a strange behaviour?

Comment: I think you'll find that the problem is having a global function with the same name as the `name` or `id` attribute of a form element, because [form control names become globals too](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-window-nameditem). Hence the error that you're seeing in the console, "submitName is not a function". (So renaming the input *or* the function should fix the problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The details are commented in the Snippet and [<kbd>PLUNKER</kbd>](http://embed.plnkr.co/hRmaa90qI0f5lCJvbu3Y/).
The Snippet will not function properly because the sandbox on SO is strict, so review the Plunker instead. Btw, the main problem is that you didn't `getItem()` with the same key as you used with `setItem()`

#### Example:

```
     On the first page: setItem('CAT', animal.value)

     On the second page: getItem('DOG');
```

That's what you basically did. `'CAT'` = `"lastName"` and `'DOG'` = `"textValue"` in your case specifically.

## NOTE: you shouldn't change the mistake in your question, it confuses the reader.

#### INDEX

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
</head>

<body onload='retrieveName()'>
  <form name="form2">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>HTML1</legend>
      <label>Last Name:
        <input type="text" id="lastName" />
      </label>
      <input type="submit" id="submitLastName" value="Save" />
    </fieldset>
    <p>(2) Click <kbd>Save</kbd>
    </p>
  </form>
  <script>
    // Reference the input lastName
    var x = document.getElementById("lastName");

    /*
    | Retrieve the stored data with the 
    | CORRECT KEY I.E. dataName
    | Assign the value of dataName as the 
    | value of x
    */
    function retrieveName(e) {
      var text = localStorage.getItem("dataName");
      x.value = text;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### HTML1

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
</head>

<body onload='retrieveName()'>
  <form name="form2">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>HTML1</legend>
      <label>Last Name:
        <input type="text" id="lastName" />
      </label>
      <input type="submit" id="submitLastName" value="Save" />
    </fieldset>
    <p>(2) Click <kbd>Save</kbd>
    </p>
  </form>
  <script>
    // Reference the input lastName
    var x = document.getElementById("lastName");

    /*
    | Retrieve the stored data with the 
    | CORRECT KEY I.E. dataName
    | Assign the value of dataName as the 
    | value of x
    */
    function retrieveName(e) {
      var text = localStorage.getItem("dataName");
      x.value = text;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
localStorage.getItem("lastName");
```

This should work. The key with which you store, is the same key with which you retrieve the value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage